# What is the Ruby on Rails-way to import a structured comma delimited file and then create records Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I have a structured comma delimited file that has two record types. The different records are differentiated by a header entry: H or P. The file format follows:

```
"H","USA","MD","20904"
"P","1","A","Female","W"
"P","2","A","Male","H"
```

I'd like to import the file and then create activerecord models with the imported data.  The approach that I am using is to create a field map that includes the number of fields, object name and columns.

I then utilize the field map

$field_map =

```
{
  'H'   =>
    {
      :count => 4,
      :object => :Header,
      :cols => [:record_type, :country_id, :state, :zip]
    },

  'R'   =>
    {
      :count => 4,
      :object => :RaceData,
      :cols => [:record_type, :household_size, :gender, :race]
    }
}
```

I then use FastCSV to import the file and use a case statement to how the file will be transformed and then used in activerecord create statements.

```
FasterCSV.foreach(filename) do |row|
    tbl_type = row[0]
    tbl_info = $field_map[tbl_type]

   unless (tbl_info.nil?)
     field_no = tbl_info[:count]
     object = tbl_info[:object]
     columns = tbl_info[:cols]
     record_type = new_record[:record_type]
     case record_type
         when "H"
         factory_build_h_record(new_record)
         when "P"
         factory_build_p_record(new_record)
     end
   end
 end
```

The code above is summarized due to space constraints.  My approach works just fine, but my I'm new to ruby and I'm always interested in best practices and the "true" Ruby-way of doing things. I'd be interested in hearing how more experienced programmers would tackle this problem.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: FYI, if you’re using Ruby 1.9, there’s no need to use FasterCSV, as Ruby 1.9’s built-in CSV library *is* FasterCSV.

Comment: Thanks.  I just checked my version and I'm still at 1.8.7.  Perhaps its time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the `gem 'roo'`

You have an example source code [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) but I rather watch the 10 min [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel)